# How to use a gem class as a model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, rubygems

I'm new to ruby and rails. I 've created a rails app that uses the [acts_as_votable gem](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable). The gem contains a class Vote that I'd like to use as a model for my app. Is it possible?

I have tried using `rails g scaffold Vote`. That way I got an empty Vote model and the appropriate controller and views. However, because acts_as_votable had already created a database table called votes `/votes` showed the pre-existing votes without their attributes. The same applies to `votes/new`, it didn't show any input fields as the new Vote class was empty.

I also thought about copying the gem class in my app but I knew it was a horrid idea.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: This seems like a misuse of the gem. Why would you want to create a vote outside of the context of a "votable" thing? What's the use case?

Comment: You 're right, it's a misuse but keep in mind that I'm a novice. It's easier for me to exploit rails functionality like scaffolding, routing and validations when I have a model, that's why I thought about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have the gem in your Gemfile, you should be able to access the `Vote` class by specifying its namespace :

```
ActsAsVotable::Vote
```

So you should be able to use it as you use other models.

It is also possible to monkey-patch the class, for instance in an initializer :

```
ActsAsVotable::Vote.send( :include, MyModule )
```

Then in another file :

```
module MyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # class eval any macro you want...
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def foo
      # define class methods...
    end
  end

  def bar
    # define instance methods...
  end
end
```

However, i would advise against doing this. It is risky to build whole parts of your business logic on a class you don't own, and is not designed to be used directly ! As long as you just add minor features, it's okay, but if you really need custom behavior, just go ahead and re-implement an 'acts_as_votable` functionnality yourserlf.

It is not so difficult nor long, and you will own your logic, which would shield you from unpredictable changes in the `Vote` class when upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use it with `ActsAsVotable::Vote`, but i think it should be used in combination with an existing Model.